# How to set up a contact form?

Tags: php, contacts, contact-form

I'm a noob in PHP. When I send the mail I only receive information about: Their name and email address.

I know that it might be very simple, but I haven't taken my time to fully learn PHP yet, hoping for answers! :)

My PHP:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_adress = $_POST['cf_adress'];
$field_post = $_POST['cf_post'];
$field_radio = $_POST['cf_radio'];

$mail_to = 'myemailadress@dsadsadsa.dsa';
$subject = 'Order from website - '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n"; <--- This one

$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n"; <--- and this one is the only fields i get in the mails :/

$body_message .= 'Adresse: '.$field_adress."\n";
$body_message .= 'Postnr/Sted: '.$field_post."\n";
$body_message .= 'Størrelse: '.$field_radio."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Success!');
        window.location = 'produkt.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('something is wrong...');
        window.location = 'websiteadress';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

My html markup:

```
    <form action="contact.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
        <div id="contentorder">
            <div class="pink">
                Fornavn og Etternavn<br />
            </div>
            <div class="black">
                <input type="text" name="cf_name" required style="width: 260px; height: 20px;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="contentorder">
            <div class="pink">
                E-Mail
            </div>
            <div class="black">
                <input type="text" name="cf_email" required style="width: 260px; height: 20px;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="contentorder">
            <div class="pink">
                Postadresse
            </div>

            <div class="black">
                <input type="text" name="cf_adress" required style="width: 260px; height: 20px;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="contentorder">
            <div class="pink">
                Postnummer og Sted<br />
            </div>

            <div class="black">
                <input type="text" name="cf_post" required style="width: 260px; height: 20px;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="contentorder">
            <div class="pink" style="width: 890px; margin-top: 20px; clear: both; ">
                Størrelse:<br />
            </div>


            <div class="radio-toolbar">

                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="cf_radio" value="XS" checked required>
                <label for="radio1">XS</label>

                <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="cf_radio" value="S" required>
                <label for="radio2">S</label>

                <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="cf_radio" value="M" required>
                <label for="radio3">M</label>

                <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="cf_radio" value="L" required>
                <label for="radio4">L</label>

                <input type="radio" id="radio5" name="cf_radio" value="XL" required>
                <label for="radio5">XL</label>

                <input type="radio" id="radio6" name="cf_radio" value="XXL" required>
                <label for="radio6">XXL</label>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="contentorder">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="buttonbest">
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: For one thing, if you're not going to use the `validateForm()` function, then get rid of `onsubmit="return validateForm();` and I'm hoping that these `----------` are not part of your code.

Comment: the --------- is not a part of the code :)  was just to point ut what information I got from this form..

Comment: try removing the onsubmit="return validateForm(); if you are not using it like @Fred -ii- said. make sure you have contact.php in the same folder as the form. If you are using everything in one file you should be using action="" or action="/"

Comment: @user3228988 comments in PHP are made like `//` or `/*`...`*/`. Not like this `<--`.

Comment: do you have any special characters in the address or other fields? it could be encoding problem and/or special characters that are breaking your code since you are not escaping it.

Comment: In your PHP, do `print_r($_POST)` to see what you are receiving. If that does not make it clear, edit what that gives you into your question (i.e. not in the comments, as it generally won't fit).

Comment: I feel so dumb, the "onsubmit="return..." was messing with the code ^^ thank you all for taking your time.. apreciate it =)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works absolutely fine with me.

I'm guessing you have special characters in the address (or in another field) that is messing with your $body_message.

For example:

```
$body_message .= 'Adresse: '.$field_adress."\n";
```

if $field_adress is "Godric's Hollow", you're going to end up with "Godric" and the \n will most likely be ignored. Make sure you escape every $_POST field before manipulating them.